# accidental turn of mouse wheel when pasting text

Tags: cut-copy-paste, mouse, linux-debian

A problem that bothers much my editing work with vim happens when pasting text and the mouse wheel rotates slightly by accident with the result that text is inserted elsewhere in the file under edition.

I tried to remove this behavior by including

```
set mouse=""
```

in my `~/.vimrc` but the annoying behavior remains.

Is there perhaps another variable that controls the mouse behavior?

Comment: You can undo by pressing u.

Comment: Another way is to check with an autocommand

Comment: in Insert mode, it doesn't matter where your mouse is pointing.. it will paste where the cursor is

Comment: Simple: don't paste with the mouse.

Comment: Maybe you need the opposite (`set mouse=a` or similar) and check your terminal/x mouse settings instead.

Comment: You could disable the mousewheel scrolling action, with `:map <ScrollWheelUp> <Nop>` etc.

Comment: @JigglyNaga Please make that an answer!

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a specific setting for disabling the wheel while leaving the other mouse features active, but as a workaround, you could map wheel events to do nothing:

```
map <ScrollWheelUp> <Nop>
map <ScrollWheelDown> <Nop>
```

You may also need to disable the shift- and control-modified events, and `Left` and `Right` if you have a device that sends those.  See `:help scroll-mouse-wheel` for a complete list of the default bindings.